# Blender Video Sequencer: I try to load 76 images, but length is 48 frames, can't change

Tags: animation, blender

In Blender 2.8, I am trying to load a sequence of already-rendered images from a previous project I did (also in 2.8, but hey, these are just .png's) into the image sequencer. I set the frame rate in the render context menu from 24fps to 30fps, which seems to have no effect on the video sequencing window, because the markers for 1 second are stuck at 24 frames. Anyway, when I try to load all 77 frames of my animation into the VS as an image sequence, I get an animation that is only 48 frames long. I can scrub through the entire sequence, but the frame count does not match the number of images in the sequence--and I can't change it. I can't even stretch the animation out. What the heck? Can somebody explain how I can make this work properly?

Comment: An image sequence strip uses the images you select when you create it. When you stretch the strip out, the new part appears clear and has no images. In the source panel there is a change data/files button, click this and select all of the images you want - that is including the images that weren't there before.

Comment: Because this question is specific to use of the Blender application, you may find you get better answers, faster, on the dedicated [Blender StackExchage](https://blender.stackexchange.com/). If you choose to post it there, please remember to delete the copy here first, as cross-posting between sites in the SE network is discouraged.